# BulkInsertAsync from EFCore.BulkExtensions doesn't seem to insert anything

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm using `EFCore.BulkExtensions` to insert batches of, at most, 100,000 records into a database.

My issue is, for some reason, `BulkInsertAsync` does not insert any records to the DB. I understand it's an asynchronous call, but I've waited half an hour and no data was inserted. The regular, synchronous `BulkInsert` call works, but is extremely suboptimal since it hogs a ton of process time.

**Does anyone have any idea why `BulkInsertAsync` doesn't work in this context, but `BulkInsert` does?**

Here is the relevant code, which marshals binary data (transmitted from another machine) into a C struct, adds that C struct to a list, and then bulk-inserts the list into the database.

```cs
            IList<object> records = new List<object>();
            using (var db = new RecordContext())
            {
                // keep going until we process all the data; numRecs is at most 100,000
                for (int i = 0; i < numRecs; i++)
                {
                    // marshal the data into the struct and map it to its database struct
                    var tempStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(dataPtr);
                    records.Add(tempStruct);
                    dataPtr += Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
                }
                db.BulkInsertAsync(records);
            }
```

Here is the relevant context code:

```cs
    public class RecordContext : DbContext
    {
        public RecordContext() : base(GetOptions()) 
        { 
            // disable change tracking for performance
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        }

        private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
        {
            return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), new Settings().recordsConnectionString).Options;
        }
        // . . .
    }
```

The following connection string is passed in from settings:
`Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;Initial Catalog=Records`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method should do something - if you await it.

So instead of:
`db.BulkInsertAsync(records);`
do:
`await db.BulkInsertAsync(records);`

Essentially, you told it to execute an async task, then you exited the method that created / owned the task by not calling await, causing the task to be abandoned. There's some subtle magic going on with the async tasks, LOL.